# search provider error on virto commerce

Tags: lucene.net, virtocommerce

I setup Virto Commerce from source code following the guide here http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1devguide/Source+code+getting+started

I set Lucene as search provider in connectionString.local.config file

```
<add name="VirtoCommerce" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=VirtoCommerce;Integrated Security = true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=420"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="SearchConnectionString" connectionString="server=~/app_data/virto/search;scope=default;provider=lucene" />
```

I don't see any index files generated here "App_Data\Virto\Search\default-catalogitem". When I try to open the site on browser I am getting following error

```
no segments* file found in Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory@C:\work\virtocommerce\src\Presentation\FrontEnd\StoreWebApp\app_data\Virto\search/default-catalogitem lockFactory=Lucene.Net.Store.NativeFSLockFactory: files:

Source Error: 


Line 251:
Line 252:            var dir = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(GetDirectoryPath(folderName)));
Line 253:            var searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir);
Line 254:
Line 255:            var q = (QueryBuilder)QueryBuilder.BuildQuery(criteria);

Source File: c:\work\virtocommerce\src\Extensions\Search\LuceneSearchProvider\LuceneSearchProvider.cs    Line: 253
```

I have run the setup-search powershell script but it doesn't help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rebuilding the search index in Commerce Manager http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc1userguide/Search+Settings

Comment: Rebuilding index from Commerece Manager helped. I wonder why it didn't create index files when I ran the powershell script.

Comment: It's because elasticsearch is the default provider in setup-search.ps1:  $searchconnection = "server=localhost:9200;scope=default;provider=elasticsearch",